# Sandboxed app autostart without ServiceManagement

Tags: macos, swift, autostart, osx-elcapitan

I am creating a sandboxed app, and have gotten autostart working with the ServiceManagement framework. However, the ServiceManagement framework is being deprecated(since Xcode 7 beta 3) for Swift as the "ServiceManagement.framework module map" now includes the line
`requires !swift`.

This produces the errors
`Could not build Objective-C module 'ServiceManagement'` and `Module 'ServiceManagement' is incompatible with the feature 'Swift'` when I try to import ServiceManagement.

How to make autostart work with Swift and without the ServiceManagement framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to add a Bridging-Header file, and in that file import the framework. It would then be available to Swift as before.

```
#import <ServiceManagement/SMLoginItem.h>
```